# Cannot modify keyboard delay and rate

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-12.04

My keyboard had been working properly for 4 months, but all of the sudden, the settings for *Delay* and *Speed* in *System Tool → System Settings → Keyboard → Typing → Repeat Keys* got ignored.

I have restarted the machine, but it didn't help.

To troubleshoot, I've even set the delay to zero, but there is still about a 1.5 second pause. Then I set it to the maximum value; there's still the same 1.5 second pause.

In addition I have attempted to rectify this from the command line

```
$ sudo kbdrate -d 250 -r 22
[sudo] password for user1: 
Typematic Rate set to 21.8 cps (delay = 250 ms)
```

Once again, the delay and rate remain unchanged after running this command.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME Classic.

Comment: What setting exactly? CCSM is the compiz settings manager. What have you set up? What have you changed? Are you sure you are using compiz?

Comment: I corrected the question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now what is this delay you have set to 0? There is a pause when doing what? What settings are being ignored?

Comment: Typing | Repeat keys.

Comment: I just found a related post  http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-978590.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to change the keyboard settings:

```
xset r rate 250 30
```

Executing `xset` shows:

```
To turn auto-repeat off or on:
    -r [keycode]        r off
     r [keycode]        r on
     r rate [delay [rate]]
```

This command worked. `kbdrate` and the System Settings GUI tools did not.